# Smallest minimum value from set of minimum values

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, terminology

Background:

> I am finding minimum distances from a certain process, and then I do
>   the same for another data set. Then from all those selected minimum
>   values, I want to get the minimum value.

In that case, if I say
***smallest minimum***, then would it be in formal English? Because I am confused how I can say minimum of minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that context, I think *smallest minimum* sounds just fine, although you'd want to be careful if:

- you're writing to a specialized audience, and the scientific literature calls for a different word to be used in that domain, or
- another word might work better than *smallest*. For example, if we were analyzing a set of  temperature readings, I'd probably recommend *lowest minimum* instead of *smallest minimum*.

Answer (score 0):

"smallest minimum value from A set of minimum values."

This means to me that you have constructed a set of values from the minimum values of several other sets and now you are referring to the smallest minimum value of a set of minimum values. If it is so your sentence is correct (it just missing the article "a").